# Where does the Hive data gets stored?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, create-table, hive-metastore

I am a little confused on where does the hive stores it's data.

Does it stores it's data in HDFS or in a RDBMS ??
Does Hive Meta store uses a RDBMS to store the hive tables metadata ??

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hive data are stored in one of [**Hadoop compatible filesystem**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/HCFS): S3, HDFS or other compatible filesystem.

Hive metadata are stored in RDBMS like MySQL, see [**supported RDBMS**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Metastore+3.0+Administration#AdminManualMetastore3.0Administration-SupportedRDBMSs).

The location of Hive tables data in S3 or HDFS can be specified for both managed and external tables.

The difference between managed and external tables is that `DROP TABLE` statement, in managed table, will drop the table and delete table's data. Whereas, for external table `DROP TABLE` will drop only the table and data will remain as is and can be used for creating other tables over it.

See details here: [**Create/Drop/Truncate Table**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable)

Comment: The link to compatible file systems is no longer alive. I found these ones which might be what it was. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/filesystem/introduction.html#Core_Expectations_of_a_Hadoop_Compatible_FileSystem

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your question. But I will suggest you to read hive books or apache hive site for better understanding.

Does it stores it's data in HDFS or in a RDBMS ?? - The Data for HIVE is always stored in HDFS. For managed tables the data is stored in hive warehouse by default which is a directory in HDFS. For HIVE External table user can specify the location anywhere in HDFS.

Does Hive Meta store uses a RDBMS to store the hive tables metadata ?? - Yes HIVE uses RDBMS to store the metadata.